# How to reference a table in another database in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

How to reference a table in another database in SQL Azure? Basically, how to make a three part reference? I get the following error:

> Reference to database and/or server name in
>   'UserLogin.dbo.aspnet_Users' is not supported in this version of SQL
>   Server.

Answer (score 3):

Azure SQL Database doesn't currently support querying remote databases (whether on same "server" or different server) within a single database connection.   You can potentially work around this limitation by opening separate connections within your application -- establishing one connection per database -- and breaking queries up.